# Calling method in MainActivity from another Class - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two classes, the MainActivity Class and a class (CognexHandler) on which i connect a USB Device .

When the Connection of the Device is completed, i want to call a method in the MainActivity Class which contains TextViwes to the activity_main.xml File.

On the initialisation of the first TextView -

```
TextView tvScanToLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScanToLogin);
```

the Programm crashes with the following error code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:183)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:763)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at de.egeplast.logistikscanner_test.MainActivity.getBatteryLevelPhone(MainActivity.java:155)
        at de.egeplast.logistikscanner_test.CognexHandler.onConnectionCompleted(CognexHandler.java:192)
        at com.cognex.mobile.barcode.sdk.ReaderDevice$7.onResponseReceived(ReaderDevice.java:668)
        at com.cognex.dataman.sdk.CommandInfo$1.run(CommandInfo.java:134)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Here the Code of the Classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ReaderDevice.ReaderDeviceListener, 
        ReaderDevice.OnConnectionCompletedListener, 
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{


        @Override
        protected void onStart() {

//      Here i start the process of connecting the device
//      The onConnectionCompleted method in the other class is called automatically on connection

        CognexHandler cognexhandler = new CognexHandler();
        CognexHandler.createReaderDevice(this); 

}


        public Integer getBatteryLevelPhone() {

        Log.d(TAG, "getBatteryLevelPhone: started");
        
        // Import Views
        TextView tvScanToLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScanToLogin); //Crashes here
        TextView tvWarning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWarning);

        //  Code that you dont have to worry about
        //

    }

}
```

```
public class CognexHandler implements
        ReaderDevice.OnConnectionCompletedListener, ReaderDevice.ReaderDeviceListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    @Override
    public void onConnectionCompleted(ReaderDevice readerDevice, Throwable throwable) {

        MainActivity mainactivity = new MainActivity();
        mainactivity.getBatteryLevelPhone();
    }


}
```

Im sure it´s something really simple and that someone can help me :)

Comment: `public Integer getBatteryLevelPhone()` It makes no sense to make such public - non static- functions as for them to be usable you would need a pointer to an activity. Which you dont have.

Answer (score 1):

> > MainActivity mainactivity = new Mainactivity();

You can not use the `new` operator to create an Activity.

You have to use an Intent to start/create an Activity.

So after that you will not have a pointer to your activity.

Well... we dont have either ;-)

Comment: And how do i call a single Method in the Mainactivity class? 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
...

Comment: 23 minutes ago i wrote a comment that explained that  you can not call public functions. Only if they are static as then you do not need a pointer.

Comment: statics won't work here because his function requires access to the views of his activity.  He needs to pass an instance of the activity to his other class.

Answer (score 0):

To add to blackapps answer, after having started the activity via the intent and if it's still  your current activity (!), in CognexHandler you can call the active activity with "getActivity()" and then make sure it's actually the correct one:

```
Activity mActivity = getActivity();
if (mActivity instanceof MainActivity) {
      final MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) mActivity;
      mainActivity.getBatteryLevelPhone(); 
}
```

I would recommend using a different way to communicate with your Activity, like Listeners or Broadcasts, this might give you a first start:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onConnectionCompleted(ReaderDevice readerDevice, Throwable throwable) {

        Activity mainActivity = getActivity();
        mainActivity.getBatteryLevelPhone();
    }
```

And Make your getBatteryLevelPhone() to:

```
public static Integer getBatteryLevelPhone(){

// your code

return yourIntegerResult;
}
```